# Python, Pandas: Faster File Search than os.path?

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have a pandas df with file names that need to be searched/matched in a directory tree.

I've been using the following but it crashes with larger directory structures. I record whether or not they are present in 2 lists.

```
found = []
missed = []

for target_file in df_files['Filename']:
    
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(DIRECTORY_TREE):
        if target_file in filenames:
            found.append(os.path.join(dirpath,target_file))
        else:
            missed.append(target_file)
print('Found: ',len(found),'Missed: ',len(missed))
print(missed)
```

I've read that scandir is quicker and will handle larger directory trees. If true, how might this be rewritten?

My attempt:

```
found = []
missed = []

for target_file in df_files['Filename']:
    
    for item in os.scandir(DIRECTORY_TREE):
        if item.is_file() and item.name() == target_file:
            found.append(os.path.join(dirpath,target_file))
        else:
            missed.append(target_file)
            
print('Found: ',len(found),'Missed: ',len(missed))
print(missed)
```

This runs (fast), but everything ends up in the "missed" list.

Comment: How does it crash? Just so I understand, `target_file` could be in multiple directories and you want to record them all?

Comment: Just freezes - doesn't do anything for minutes. About 2500 files. There is one top-level directory with 25 subdirs - each subdir may have 1 or more subdirs below that.

Comment: taking a long time is not the same as crashing :) you could use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) to get a progress bar while it's running - I find this really helpful for keeping my sanity during long-running jobs

Comment: In your view, this is the most efficient way then? I have 2 even larger collections to go through - maybe triple this size - and I worry that this method may just not be up to the task.

Comment: if you want to write this with scandir, can you show us what you have tried? I've never used it, but "please rewrite my working code for me in a different framework" isn't an allowed question type on stack overflow. give it a shot and show us where (if) you get stuck. good luck!

Comment: Fair enough. Was looking for some kind of entry point and apparently scandir takes a bit more plumbing than os,walk does.

Comment: yeah. you might get an answer :) I hope you do!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado see update. First attempt prints everything as "missed". Not possible.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should put the directory scan before iterating over the pandas df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan your directories only once and convert it to a dataframe.

Example on my `venv` directory:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

DIRECTORY_TREE = pathlib.Path('./venv').resolve()
data = [(str(pth.parent), pth.name) for pth in DIRECTORY_TREE.glob('**/*') if pth.is_file()]
df_path = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Directory', 'Filename'])

df_files = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': ['__init__.py']})
```

Now you can use `df_path` to lookup filenames from `df_files` with `merge`:

```
out = (df_files.merge(df_path, on='Filename', how='left')
               .value_counts('Filename').to_frame('Found'))
out['Missed'] = len(df_path) - out['Found']
print(out.reset_index())

# Output
      Filename  Found  Missed
0  __init__.py   5837  105418
```

Comment: @EABubnoff. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. Will test very shortly and get back to you.